# What does “only on this Earth to reproduce” mean？

Tags: meaning

> Errol Musk, 76, believes he's **only on this Earth to reproduce**, he told The Sun. And so he did it for a second time with his 35-year-old stepdaughter who he's raised since she was 4. In 2018, it was revealed that he had an unplanned child--Elliot Rush, now 5--with Jana Bezuidenhout, Tesla exec and billionaire Elon Musk's step-sister. Errol Musk told The Sun he had a daughter in 2019 with Bezuidenhout, too, also unplanned. He was married to Bezuidenhout's mother for 18 years, and they had two children." If I could have another child I would," Errol musk told The Sun,"I can't see any reason not to."

What does "only" mean? Is "only" an adverb or adjective? Does it mean that he's the only and sole person on this Earth to reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'*Only*' means that for Errol Musk reproduction is the ***single*** (only) ***thing*** he is '*on this Earth for*' (alive for).

In other words: Errol Musk thinks his only purpose in life is to procreate.

Comment: Thank you. Is "only" an adverb or adjective?

Comment: @Tyrion An adverb. It modifies the verb 'to be', here in the form of 'is' or "'s" ("he's").